# ElasticSearch - Setting doc_values on existing index

Tags: elasticsearch

According to [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata-formats.html):

> It is possible to change the field data format (and the field data settings in general) on a live index by using the update mapping API.

But when I try:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://es1:123/my_index/my_type/_mapping' -d '
{
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "my_prop": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "fielddata": {
                    "format": "doc_values"
                },
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                    "hash": {
                        "type": "murmur3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [my_prop] has different doc_values values]}]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-create the mapping for your index and to re-index all the documents in it.

You don't have `doc_values` enabled for that field: `"doc_values": true`. But you want your fielddata format to be `doc_values`. This is not possible.

To be able to change the fielddata format from whatever format **to** `doc_values` and vice-versa you need to have doc_values enabled: `"doc_values": true`. Note, though, that even if doc_values are not enabled you can freely change any in-memory format, meaning anything from `fst` to `paged_bytes` and vice-versa is possible.

Comment: The documentation is correct, but there is a tricky part with `doc_values`. You need to have them enabled to use fielddata as `doc_values`. Which sounds obvious if you think about it a bit.